# Android- Kotlin: how can i measure and detect covered area by a finger touch on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors, android-hardware, sensormanager

I want to know how much area my finger covers when I touch the phone screen.
I used many sensors for some events. I compile my code with Android Studio. They asked this question 11 years ago but the motionEvent.getSize() response is not working or not correct answer.

Can you help me about this Sensor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most devices are not capable of detecting touch size and so `motionEvent.size` will always be 0 or 1 on most devices. Apple made a big deal out of their first phones that could detect pressure (which is used to estimate touch size), but since the feature is not heavily used, they've stopped even putting it in their newest flagship phones. On Android, only a tiny fraction of devices ever supported pressure sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate that manually in onTouchEvent() MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.

Here is an article for your reference: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

This will help a lot but you will have to figure out calculations.